# Is it okay to have multiple GA4 tags in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Is it okay to have multiple Google Analytics 4 configuration tags in Tag Manager reporting to multiple GA4 properties? If so, how many?

In the past, it was recommended to only have a website report to a single property, which was okay because you could put in separate views. But now that there aren't any views in GA4 properties, I'm trying to find out if I can safely have multiple GA4 properties in my tag container for raw data, experimental view, and primary reporting view.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, the isn't a limit.

Anyway this sentence is wrong:

> In the past, it was recommended to only have a website report to a single property

...if so you could not implement cross-domain (in reference to Universal Analytics).